# getting the top_n closest rows to the first row in a data frame

Tags: r

I thought I ask the experts - sorry this is more like a code review question but I add to it below. Is the following code OK to obtain the top_n closest cases to the first row - ignoring the first row:

```
example_df <- data.frame(
                  gender = c("male", "male", "female", "male")
                , age = c(30, 30.1, 20, 31)
              )
example_df

gower_dist <- as.matrix(daisy(example_df, metric = "gower"))
gower_dist

top_n <- 2

# select top 2 closest row indices of row 1
example_df[head(order(gower_dist[-1, 1]), top_n) + 1,]
```

I tried to get this to work for the 3rd row as well but this does not work:

```
example_df[head(order(gower_dist[-3, 3]), top_n) + 1,]
```

Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

PS:

distance metric:

```
            1           2         3          4
1 0.000000000 0.004545455 0.9545455 0.04545455
2 0.004545455 0.000000000 0.9590909 0.04090909
3 0.954545455 0.959090909 0.0000000 1.00000000
4 0.045454545 0.040909091 1.0000000 0.00000000
```

Comment: `example_df[head(order(gower_dist[-1,1]), top_n + 1),]` should get you three rows

Comment: @akash87 not sure what your point is example_df[head(order(gower_dist[-1, 1]), top_n) + 1,] gets me the top 2 closest rows to row 1 as expected.

Comment: I thought you wanted the top 3 rows based on what I was reading. Was I misinterpreting this?

Comment: top_n <- 2 - clearly specified. i am asking (1) does example_df[head(order(gower_dist[-1, 1]), top_n) + 1,]  work to get the top 2 closest rows to row 1 as expected. What would be the equivalent to get the top 2 closest rows to row 3. This is not producing expected results: example_df[head(order(gower_dist[-3, 3]), top_n) + 1,]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `diag` to `NA` will make subsetting easier.

```
diag(gower_dist)  <- NA
example_df[head(order(gower_dist[, 1]), top_n),]
#  gender  age
#2   male 30.1
#4   male 31.0

example_df[head(order(gower_dist[, 3]), top_n),]
#  gender  age
#1   male 30.0
#2   male 30.1
```

You remove col 3 with `gower_dist[-3, 3]` but `order` does still give you values from 1 to 3 and not 1,2 and 4.

Answer (score 2):

Using @GKi's suggestion of setting the diagonal elements of the distance matrix to NA,

```
diag(gower_dist)  <- NA
```

we can also use `dplyr::top_n`

```
library(dplyr)

n <- 2
row <- 3

example_df %>% 
  top_n(n, -gower_dist[, row])

#   gender  age
# 1   male 30.0
# 2   male 30.1
```